# Vue 3 Element-Plus table could not show axios result when I use script set up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue 3 (setup) + element plus table + axios to render table data.However, I get the data in api result but it never shows to the table view.

I would like to use new `script-setup`.

I think it is not related to element-plus and `tableData` is not responsive in my code. but I am not sure how to declare it in this condition.

My Vue file:

```
<template>
  <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="250">
     
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="type" label="Type" align="center" width="150">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="description" label="Desc" align="center" width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="income" label="Income" align="center" width="170">
     
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="expend" label="Expand" align="center" width="170">
     
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="cash" label="Cash" align="center" width="170">
     
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="remark" label="Remark" align="center" width="220">
    </el-table-column>
   
  </el-table>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>

import { reactive,getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

interface Profile {
  date: string,
  description: string,
  expend: string,
  income: string,
  type: string,
  remark: string
}

const app = getCurrentInstance();

let tableData:Profile[] = reactive([]);

const getAllProfile = () => {
  app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$axios
    .get("/api/profiles")
    .then((res) => {
      tableData= res.data;
      console.log(tableData);//show data successfully in console
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

getAllProfile();
</script>
```

**Update**

It seems that I need to use some nested structure like:

```
let tableData = reactive({
    arr:[]//store the table data here
})
```

And use `tableData.arr` at anywhere I need to use the data.Why it designs like that?

As xigua2022 said that I could also use `ref` instead and it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let tableData = reactive([]); -> let tableData = ref([]);
tableData = res.data; -> tableData.value = res.data;

Comment: It works.But why does it not work using reactive?

Comment: @Ryan reactive is meant for objects with properties. Arrays in JavaScript are a bit special and even if `typeof [] === 'object'` they behave a bit differently. That is why it is better to use a `ref` or as you found out as a property within an object.